# ghcInvocation: the programVersion must not be Nothing

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am trying to upgrade my Yesod project to version 1.1 and it was working fine with version 1.0. Now I am trying to run my project on version 1.1. When trying to run `yesod --dev devel` I get the following error:

```
cabal-dev: user error (Warning: cannot determine version of /home/user/.cabal/bin/fake-ghc-cabal-dev
:
"== GHC Arguments: Start ==\n--numeric-version\n== GHC Arguments: End ==\n"
cabal: ghcInvocation: the programVersion must not be Nothing
)
yesod: readProcess: cabal-dev "buildopts" (exit 1): failed
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: If more information is required, I will happily provide it not sure what is required though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem exactly was, but upgrading cabal-dev, cabal-install and cabal did the trick.

```
cabal install cabal-dev cabal-install cabal
```

Comment: @scvalex Maybe Joost waits if somebody posts an answer explaining what the problem exactly was before accepting his own answer. That's a good strategy, IMO, post the fix you found, and wait if somebody can give a better answer.

Comment: You also need to wait 2 days before you can accept your own answer anyway. (maybe that's limited by my reputation)